# Laravel Eloquent find rows where date older than 27 days and 29-49 days

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get rows that are < 27 days from the user-selected date and 29-49 days. We allow users to select the date range for eg. `from_date` to `to_date` and within the provided date. I want to get rows that are < 27 days and 29-49 days from `created_at`.

I can use raw queries, please help.

This is what I have tried but not getting results.

```
Model::where('created_at','>=',Carbon::parse($from_date)->subDays(27))
       ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($to_date)->subDays(27))
       ->get();
```

Comment: Did you try using `whereDate()`?

Comment: Try `Model::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::parse($from_date)->subDays(27), Carbon::parse($to_date)->subDays(27)])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
Model::->where( 'created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(27))
  ->orWhereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subDays(29), Carbon::now()->subDays(49)])
  ->get();
```